# Magento 2.3.X css updated after certain time in custom theme

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, css, cache

I have used Porto theme and create a child theme with custom CSS file. Sometime css is not updated instantly and take certain time to update.

I have already contacted the server support and they told there is no issue of the server and must be an issue of my file.

**I have already performed the following actions  :**

> 1. Remove pub/static, var/cache, var/page_cache
> 2. Deploy theme
> 3. Cache refresh

Anyone have an idea regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

I had your same problem and solved it by disabling the server cache.

I had the nginx and varnish cache active
If you put the site in developer mode do you have the same error?